# Converting JQuery to AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

To make matters simple, I have two types of css items:

```
 <style>
 .minified nav>ul>li>a .menu-item-parent,.minified nav>ul>li>a>b {
     display: none;
 }
 .minified #leftMenu {
    width: 45px;
  }
 </style>
```

And the following JavaScript:

```
     // COLLAPSE LEFT NAV
$('.minifyme').click(function(e) {
    $('body').toggleClass("minified");
    $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 500);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

As you can see, on click two events occur:

1. The left menu width is reduced to 45px;
2. The text to the menu system becomes display:none.

![enter image description here][1]

I understand how angular manages to toggle a single class or id with ng-class, but not with multiple css elements, as in this case: #leftMenu & < li > items.

Would anyone like to offer up some ideas?

Thanks

I had a pic to better illustrate but apparently "wisdom" dictates I must have more points to do so.

**I tried this, it did not work:**

```
  <aside id="left-panel" data-ng-controller="SideMenuCtrl as vm" data-ng-class="{ minified: vm.menuOpen }">
       ......
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Typography</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Pricing Tables</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Invoice</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" target="_top">Login</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" target="_top">Register</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" target="_top">Locked Screen</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Error 404</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Error 500</a>
                </li>
               </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<span><a data-ng-click="vm.toggleMenu"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left hit"></i></a></span>
...

  </aside>


  <script>

   angular.module('app').controller(controllerId,
    ['$scope', SideMenuCtrl]);

function SideMenuCtrl($scope) {
  .....
    vm.menuOpen = true;
    vm.toggleMenu = function(){
      vm.menuOpen = !vm.menuOpen;
        };
 ...
```

**Hurrah, got it to work, my bad in forgetting vm. in aside tag. ie. { minified: vm.menuOpen }"**

Comment: See adj comment above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
myApp.controller('MainController', function($scope){
    $scope.menuOpen = false;
    $scope.toggleMenu = function(){
        $scope.menuOpen = !scope.menuOpen;
    };
});
```

And then you could use this property to assign any css class you want. E.g:

```
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController"><body ng-class="{ minified: menuOpen }">
```

Comment: How does that trigger the various items, as in this case, the menu text being non display and the width 45px? I see what you are doing but I fail to see how you are triggering the various css elements.

Comment: With the 'menuOpen' property on the scope you can set any class, on any element, where needed. The rest is just plain CSS. You can also use 'ng-show' to show / hide elements.

Comment: And if you want to get fancy, you can use animations in combination with 'ng-show'. See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow.